# Как сформировать путь к директории в корне сайта?

Tags: php, файлы, файловая-система

Как можно реализовать такую задачу - есть файл response.php, который может находится на сайте где угодно, например vendor/lib/path/to/plugin/response.php относительно корня, он принимает параметр такого типа 'images/subdir' где images - это директория в корне сайта. Файл response.php должен сформировать путь к этой папке относительно себя, то есть что-то типа ../../../../../images/subdir
Вариант с $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'images/subdir' не годится, он вернет путь к файловой системе сайта типа home/site.ru/public_html/images/subdir, и именно относительный путь, абсолютный тоже не вариант. И самое главное - мы никогда не знаем, где будет находится сам файл обработчик. Он может лежать как в корне, так и в папке с люой вложенностью. Буду очень признателен за любую помощь.
Код response.php

```
<?php
// этот файл может находиться где угодно в файловой системе сайта
// например в vendor/lib/path/to/plugins/testplugin/helper
$dir = 'images/subdir';
// 'images/subdir' - искомая директория, путь может быть любым, главное что images - это папка в корне сайта
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), 
                        \RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD);
$results = null;
            foreach ($iterator as $fileInfo) {
            $results[] = array(
// тут надо получить путь типа  ../../../../../images/subdir/01.jpg
            "path" => str_replace("\\","/", $fileInfo->getPathname()),
);
}
```

если сделать

```
<?php
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'images/subdir';
```

то в "path" получаем C://OpenServer/domains/site.loc/images/subdir/01.jpg
а надо ../../../../../images/subdir/01.jpg
дело в том, что обработчик возвращает $results в джаваскрипт, а тому нужны правильные пути для вывода картинок

Comment: Вы можете разбить абсолютный путь на части(например explode) найти первое расхождение в путях и собрать относительный путь посчитав глубину расхождений. В любом случае вам нужно знать абсолютные или относительные пути до скриптов чтобы высчитать разницу или проводить сканирование всех папок и поиск файла

Comment: Вот и я думал, что у меня получится так сделать, но не хватает логики как правильно такое закодить. Другими словами, чукча не писатель, чукча читатель)) Интуитивно понимаю, а написать кодом не могу, нужна помощь

Comment: @Volloff Погодите а чем вам `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` не угодил? Вы директиву `__DIR__` пробовали? `echo "This file dir: " . __DIR__;`

Comment: Если нужна помощь - давайте конкретику, решать задачу за вас я не стану, она слишком скучная и до нелепости тривиальная. А вот помочь вам понять как ее решить - это с радостью. Алгоритм прост, если его вы понять не можете, берем два абсолютных пути до скрипта 1 и 2, разбиваем их на массивы(explode) в цикле проверяем что элементы с одинаковым индексом равны... как только находим где они не равны считаем сколько уровней осталось в каждом из массивов, из одного из массивов получаем кол-во оставшихся папок и делаем переходы вверх, затем добавляем к нему остаток первого массива собранный в путь

Comment: Я же говорю, интуитивно я понимаю суть алгоритма, но на на php я это сам не напишу. Более конкретно по задаче - мы должны получить имена файлов и папок в заданной папке. Я это написал с помощью RecursiveIteratorIterator, но мой код возвращает пути в виде C:\OpenServer\domains\site.loc\images\ , а это не то

Comment: Тогда стоит добавить ваш код в вопрос, описать что на выходе и что должно быть ;)

Comment: Добавил код, возможно будет понятнее

Comment: вот что-что а `..` при выводе картинок в хтмл вам точно не надо. если картинки в корне сайта, то и выводить их надо ссылкой на `src="/images/sub/x.jpg"` и никак иначе. Сама папка vendor котоую вы упомянули никогда не находится в корне сайта а лежит  на уровень выше. так что сомнительно, что относительная директория вам чем-то вообще пригодится при построении путей.

Comment: а что же надо? в src какой должен быть путь?

Comment: я не знаю, куда юзер засунет папку с плагином в файловой системе сайта. vendor - это для примера